# check in the collection,what id has no records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have few ids in array

```
  var editions= ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd",......,"zzz"]
```

I have a collection called `participants`

it has the record called `edition`

```
edition:"aaa"
```

now I want which ids  in the `editions array` which has no records in `participants` collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want all of this to happen on the server then you can use the aggregation framework and the set features available, notably the [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator from MongoDB 2.6 and greater:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "editionsFound": { "$addToSet": "$edition" } 
    }},
    { "$project": {
       "notFound": {
           "$setDifference": [
               editions,
               "$editionsFound"
           ]
       }
    }}
])
```

Or you can just do this on the client performing a difference between the result and original via the `.distinct()` method:

```js
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

var result = db.collection.distinct("edition");

editions.diff(result);
```

Or some similar approach in your language of choice.

Either way means getting the distinct values and comparing it to your source list to find the difference.

Comment: Very Nice Solution ! `$setDifference`